# Why is Russia threatening Ukraine *now*?

Tags: donald-trump, russian-federation, ukraine, nato

[What does Russian government have to gain from the current build up and threatening possible invasion of Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70052/what-does-russian-government-have-to-gain-from-the-current-build-up-and-threaten) answers why Russia is threatening Ukraine, but not why it has waited to do it in 2022 instead of a few years ago when the Trump administration was reputedly more accommodating to Russian interests.

Why now?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why does Putin want to attack Ukraine in the early 2022?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70484) It's closed as a duplicate of the one you mention but it's at 4 reopen votes currently.

Comment: It is close, but doesn't mention the possibility that Trump may be more obliging than Biden. I feel that's an important distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure if that makes your question fundamentally different. The way I see it, the US president is just one factor that could answer your title question. But whether that's actually part of the Russian decision-making on this issue is hard to say, it calls for internal motivation of Russia's actions. I guess you could focus on that factor by asking what, if any, expert analyses link the change in US presidency (or US foreign policy more broadly) to increased Russian activity in the Ukraine conflict.

Comment: Voting to reopen since [this source](https://www.economist.com/by-invitation/2022/03/11/john-mearsheimer-on-why-the-west-is-principally-responsible-for-the-ukrainian-crisis) provides an explanation for why Russia is threatening Ukraine now (end 2021-present).

Comment: @Allure how is that a reason to vote to reopen?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I suppose one could vote to reopen the linked duplicate, as well. The linked duplicate to the linked duplicate, however, addresses a different quesiton.